# text isn't showing after using setText() to TextView() in inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, layout-inflater, settext

Yes, I know that similar questions were asked before but I tried many of those. So I have a problem with setting text in TextView in the inflated layout. I tried setContentView() then it works but then activity_main.xml with the menu isn't working. So I tried to inflate layout with TextView that I need. When I try to setText() it just doesn't displaying it. Here is my code:

```
public void bodAlg() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1,  null);  

    EditText editText = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.bod_servers);
    String[] serversArray = editText.getText().toString().split(", ");

    TextView textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.bod_serv_array);
    textView.setText(Arrays.toString(serversArray));
}
```

And here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bod_servers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cray CS-Storm, Vulcan – Blue Gene/Q, Blue Gene/Q, Stampede – PowerEdge C8220, Piz Daint – Cray XC30"
            android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bod_serv_array"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you for answer!

Comment: Debug it and see if the variable `serversArray` is not empty

Comment: Already tried this, it isn't

Comment: How are you using this method? It's very strange that you inflate a view with no parent (`View vi`), then look up children views in that newly-inflated view, and then throw everything away. Why would you expect to be able to see text set to a `TextView` that isn't added to the screen?

Comment: It look like you are inflating the view but then you don't do anything with it.  you may need to attach it to a root view and call invalidate() on that root view to redraw it.

Comment: @BenP. I add my xml, and I don't understand why I can get text using getText() but I can't set it with setText()

Comment: You are setting it. However, you never add the inflated layout to anything onscreen, so you never see it. That's what Ben meant by "throw everything away".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comments! Problem is solved!

```
public void bodAlg() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1,  null);  

    EditText editText = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.bod_servers);
    String[] serversArray = editText.getText().toString().split(", ");

    TextView textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.bod_serv_array);
    textView.setText(Arrays.toString(serversArray));

    // solution 
    CoordinatorLayout mainL = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    mainL.removeAllViews(); // remove previous view, add 2nd layout
    mainL.addView(vi);
}
```